# python compare strings in a table and return the best string

Tags: python, compare

I have a table with 3 columns delimited by whitespaces

```
A1 3445 1  24
A1 3445 1 214
A2 3603 2  45
A2 3603 2 144
A0 3314 3   8
A0 3314 3 134
A0 3314 4  46
```

I would like to compare the last column with the ID (e.g. A1) in the first column to return the string with biggest number. So, the end result will be like this.

```
A1 3445 1 214
A2 3603 2 144
A0 3314 3 134
```

I have done up to spliting the lines, but I don't get how to compare the line.
A help would be nice.

Comment: What is a "data table"?

Comment: I fixed the "data table" to just a table.

Comment: Is it a pandas dataframe, a csv file, a nested list, ...?

Comment: just a whitespace delimited file.

Answer (score 0):

```
dataDic = {}
for data in open('1.txt').readlines():
    id, a, b ,num = data.split(" ")
    if not dataDic.has_key(id):
        dataDic[id] = [a, b, int(num)]
    else:
       if int(num) >= dataDic[id][-1]:
           dataDic[id] = [a, b, int(num)]

print dataDic
```

I think, maybe this result is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `sorted` function, giving the last column as the key

```
with open('a.txt', 'r') as a:  # 'a.txt' is your file
    table = []
    for line in a:
        table.append(line.split())

s = sorted(table, key=lambda x:int(x[-1]), reverse=True)
for r in s:
    print '\t'.join(r)
```

Result:

```
A1  3445    1   214
A2  3603    2   144
A0  3314    3   134
A0  3314    4   46
A2  3603    2   45
A1  3445    1   24
A0  3314    3   8
```

Comment: thank you, but as it is not sort, I do not need the last four lines.

Comment: You can redefine s: `s = sorted(table, key=lambda x:int(x[-1]), reverse=True)[:3]`

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [('A1',3445,1,24),  ('A1',3445,1,214), ('A2',3603,2,45),
        ('A2',3603,2,144), ('A0',3314,3,8),   ('A0',3314,3,134), 
        ('A0',3314,4, 46)]

from itertools import groupby
for  key, group in groupby(data, lambda x: x[0]):
    print sorted(group, key=lambda x: x[-1], reverse=True)[0]
```

The output is:

```
('A1', 3445, 1, 214)
('A2', 3603, 2, 144)
('A0', 3314, 3, 134)
```

You can use this function [groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).